# Show cassandra help documentation in terminal instead of browser

Tags: cassandra, command-line

I've just started playing around with Cassandra through the cqlsh cli. When using the help command for the topics the documentation opens in the browser. Is there a way to show the documentation in the terminal and not open the browser for this? I can't find any descriptions on how to do it and my google searches doesn't turn up anything. I'm using Apache cassandra cqlsh 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [cqlsh reference documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html):

> cqlsh help displays in the terminal. **CQL help is only available online in HTML**.

You can download offline documentation in PDF & HTML formats from [DataStax documentation site](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/docList.html).